# Matplotlib figures gets bigger when updated in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, pysimplegui

I'm new in PySimpleGui and I want to plot a function which takes a variable in a slider. My problem is that when I update the value of the variable through the slider, the plot window becomes bigger each time. Any solution for that?
Here is my minimal working code:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import PySimpleGUI as sg
import math
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,\
                                              NavigationToolbar2Tk


def fun(nu):
    x=np.arange(1,10,0.1)
    plt.plot(x,nu*x)
    return plt.gcf()

sg.theme('SandyBeach')  

layout = [

    [sg.Text('nu_min', size =(15, 1)), sg.InputText(0.2,key='-nu_min-')],
    [sg.Text('nu_max', size =(15, 1)), sg.InputText(1,key='-nu_max-')],    
    [sg.Text('nu_step', size =(15, 1)), sg.InputText(0.1,key='-nu_step-')],

    [sg.Submit('Run'), sg.Cancel()]
]
window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
event, values = window.read()
window.close()


nu_min=float(values['-nu_min-'])
nu_max=float(values['-nu_max-'])
nu_step=float(values['-nu_step-'])


def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg

def delete_figure_agg(figure_agg):
    figure_agg.get_tk_widget().forget()
    plt.close('all')
figure_w, figure_h = 400, 400

layout = [[sg.Text('Graph Element Combined with Math!', justification='center', relief=sg.RELIEF_SUNKEN, expand_x=True, font='Courier 18')],
          [sg.Button('Plot'), sg.Cancel(), sg.Button('Popup')],
          [sg.Canvas(size=(figure_w, figure_h), key='-CANVAS-')],
          [sg.Text('nu', font='Courier 14'), sg.Slider((nu_min,nu_max),default_value=nu_min,resolution=nu_step, orientation='h', enable_events=True, key='-slider_nu-', expand_x=True)]]

window = sg.Window('', layout, finalize=True)
figure_agg = None
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if figure_agg:
        # ** IMPORTANT ** Clean up previous drawing before drawing again
        delete_figure_agg(figure_agg)    
    fig=fun(values['-slider_nu-'])
    figure_agg = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)
    
window.close()
```

Comment: Don't use `plt` which is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, try to use `Figure` which `from matplotlib.figure import Figure` to draw the figure embedded in Canvas/Graph element. Refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/5410

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and see that your Y values shrink and grow as the slider is changed. Is this what you mean when you say, "the plot window becomes bigger..."

If so, try setting the Xlim and Ylim values to limit your plot values. When I inserted this into your code, the Y values are fixed at 10, and the plot updates as I move the slider.

```
    def fun(nu):
      x=np.arange(1,10,0.1)
      plt.xlim(10)
      plt.ylim(10)
      plt.plot(x,nu*x)
      return plt.gcf()
```